# Mongoose hangs and I don't have any connection errors

Tags: linux, node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose

I am working on my ubuntu, and this always hangs :

```
router.route('/articles')

    // get all the articles (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/articles)
        .get(function(req, res) {
            Article.find().sort('-created_at').exec(function(err, articles) {
                if (err) 
                    res.send(err);
                res.json(articles);
            });
        });
```

but not just this one, it seems to be the same with all my collections, but I can see them fine in mongo shell or Robomongo.
I don't think it is a connection error because I don't have any :

```
// database
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
console.log(config.database);
mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err) {
     if (err) {
        console.err(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected');
    }    
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
     if (err) {
        console.err(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected');
    }    
});
```

Dont know if it's relevant but I have warnings when using the mongo shell :

2015-09-08T19:07:12.200+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-09-08T19:07:12.200+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. rlimits set to 31125 processes, 64000 files. Number of processes should be at least 32000 : 0.5 times number of files.

I am very surprised because it worked just a few days ago, I am starting to think I may have a problem with my system.

FYI my full project on github : https://github.com/mael-jarnole/website

I have been struggling with this issue the whole afternoon, and could'nt get anything done.

console

> ```
>    ---------$ nodemon server.js
>     8 Sep 19:26:19 - [nodemon] v1.4.1
>     8 Sep 19:26:19 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
>     8 Sep 19:26:19 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
>     8 Sep 19:26:19 - [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
>     mongodb://localhost:27017/test
>     Listening on: 8080
>     css file written on disk successfully !
>     Connected
>     Something is happening with the API.
> ```

Comment: Does the callback fire? Put a console.log in there.

Comment: Sorry, yes the callback on the connection does fire, but no error. And the second callback does not.

Comment: I was referring to the callback to `Article.find()`, I am unsure what 'second callback' you're referring to

Comment: I thought you were talking about the callbacks for mongoose connection. No the Article.find() callback doesn't fire either.

Comment: I cloned my project on my windows partition, did npm install and it works :/ I guess something broke on my Linux, but I have no idea what I should be looking for.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you fix it?

Comment: @Neta I've just faced this issue. Did you fix it?) And it also doesn't work on Linux, but works on Windows..

Comment: @Yuriy It got resolved somehow. Sorry but I can't remember how.